# Scan QR Code in Unity using ZXing and AR Core

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, zxing, arcore, zxing.net

I'm trying to scan a QR code in Unity using the libraries ZXing and AR Core. 
Currenty I tried the following:

```
private void _OnImageAvailable(TextureReaderApi.ImageFormatType format, int width, int height, IntPtr pixelBuffer, int bufferSize)
{
    // pixelBuffer is input image
    byte[] s_ImageBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];     // output image

    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(pixelBuffer, s_ImageBuffer, 0, bufferSize);

    //m_EdgeDetectionBackgroundTexture = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.R8, false, false);
    m_EdgeDetectionBackgroundTexture = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false, false);
    m_EdgeDetectionBackgroundTexture.LoadRawTextureData(s_ImageBuffer);
    m_EdgeDetectionBackgroundTexture.Apply();

    var cameraFeed = m_EdgeDetectionBackgroundTexture.GetPixels32();

    BarcodeReader barCodeReader = new BarcodeReader();
    var data = barCodeReader.Decode(cameraFeed, width, height);
    if (data != null)
    {
        // QRCode detected.
        Debug.Log(data.Text);

        //ResultPoints[0].X=bottom right
        //ResultPoints[2].X=top right
        //ResultPoints[2].Y=top left
        //ResultPoints[0].X=bottom left
        Debug.LogError(data.ResultPoints[0].X);
        Debug.LogError(data.ResultPoints[2].X);
        Debug.LogError(data.ResultPoints[2].Y);
        Debug.LogError(data.ResultPoints[0].Y);
        Debug.LogError(data.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("No QR code detected !");
    }

}
```

But it seems like no QR code can be detected. Is there anything I could do to extract an image from a AR Core Camera and extract the QR code from it?

Comment: Is `data` equal to `null`?

Comment: Yes, it displays the message: "No QR code detected!"